# realloc causing memory map error SIGABRT

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm facing some problem with reallocating an array of array of char. When I try to debug it with GDB, I got `realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00000000006042f0 error`. Here's the code:

```
int wordCount = 1;
int charCount = 1;
char** words = (char**)malloc(wordCount*sizeof(char*));
char* words[0] = (char*)malloc(charCount*sizeof(char));
char c = getNextChar(file);//it will read the content of the file character by character
while(c!='\0')//read
{
    words[wordCount-1] = (char*)realloc(words[wordCount-1],(charCount+1)*sizeof(char));
    charCount++;
    c = getNextChar(file);
    if(c=='\n' || c==' ')
    {
         words = (char**)realloc(words, (countWord+1)*sizeof(char*)); //this is where I got the error
         wordCount++;
         c = getNextChar(file);
    }
}
```

any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Is this the real code? The line KarthikT points out should give some compiler warnings at least.

Comment: Please be sure that the code in your post is the actual code. It is very difficult to help you otherwise. Copy and paste from the editor or IDE. Don't re-write it, and avoid editing it after pasting.

Comment: Did you `#include` `<stdlib.h>`? Also: There is no reason to and also no gain casting the result of `malloc()`/`realloc()` in C, even more: doing so tends to hide errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* words[0] = (char*)malloc(charCount*sizeof(char));
```

If this is actually in your code (it [errors out for me](http://codepad.org/qcKDU7es)), try to remove the first `char*`.